# # anchor not working

Tags: internet-explorer, anchor

on website page when video is played from any tab.. .say puppet shows.. then pag gets post back.. and after page reloads video gets loaded and then control goes to #puppetshow anchor which is that particular tab.

http://testkids.dadabhagwan.org.gall.arvixe.com/gallery/videos/dalo+tarvadi/puppet+shows/#puppetshows

This work fine in FireFox, but not in IE. In IE Url is not generated with #.
http://testkids.dadabhagwan.org.gall.arvixe.com/gallery/videos/neel+ane+keri+part-2/puppet+shows/

Any solution for this?

Comment: Generated from where exactly? Where does the link come from?

Comment: link come from .aspx.cs code ...

Answer (score 0):

I triied it and it didn't work on Internet Explorer. But When I selected the address bar in IE  and hit enter, it worked.

You may make a workaround by adding a javascript in the jQuery document ready (which will fix behavior on IE and work on other browsers too) like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
document.location.href = document.location.href;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Works fine in ie too. I tested on ie 7.

http://testkids.dadabhagwan.org.gall.arvixe.com/gallery/videos/dalo+tarvadi/puppet+shows/#puppetshows

means that it will open the page http://testkids.dadabhagwan.org.gall.arvixe.com/gallery/videos/dalo+tarvadi/puppet+shows and then browser will scroll down to html element with `id=puppetshows` .

ie. it does not involve selecting that particular tab. ( In ie too, it scrolls down to element with id=puppetshows

A javascript in your code will be selecting the tab with particular hash. You need to look into that javascript code. There's no problem in ie regarding hash.